# AWS CDK Secrets Manager get secret from centralized account in different accounts, via Code Pipeline at deployment time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-secrets-manager

I have three AWS accounts: Security (centralized account for definition of users, secrets, code pipeline) and Prod and Dev accounts (accessed by users in the Security account using assume roles and where the code pipeline from the Security account deploys resources).

I have two secrets (representing the same thing but for Dev and Prod) which i need to use inside a Lambda function. The thing is i don't want to call the secrets manager get secret from inside the Lambda function since that would incur in high costs (adding the prod and dev invocation of the function would add up to 40K+ every hour). There is not a problem currently with the secrets to be available in the template or in the functions.

I tried implementing this, by generating a SecretsStack that basically creates and deploys the secrets to the Security account, as well as a customer managed CMK (since the secrets will be accessed by different accounts than where defined I read the docs this needed to be done, since the AWS managed one doesn't allow cross account access). I also grant read access for the Prod and Dev secrets to the Prod and Dev assumed roles respectively. At this point, i can acccess, for example, the Dev secret by calling the secretsmanager get-secret-value from the cli using the Dev assumed role and it works.

The problem arises when I try passing the created secret in my cdk app as a prop to my LambdaStack (where it will be used). Inside the LambdaStack i do props.mySecretPassedAsProps.secretValueFromJson(key).unsafeUnwrap() to access a particular key of my json structure secret. After pushing to my tracked github branch from Code Pipeline i see it fails to find the secret when creating the Lambda function.
[lambda function creation failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD7pp.png)

After checking the template i also find that it is not resolving to the secret value even though is use the unsafeUnwrap method, showing something like:

'{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:'

Been banging my head around this all day and can't seem to find a solution can someone shed a light?

Thanks in advance!

The full description of the problem is above

Comment: The template value is a CloudFormation [dynamic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) to the secret.  This is expected.  In the happy case, CloudFormation resolves the secret value at deploy-time.  The [docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-secretsmanager) cross-account resolution is supported (with full secret name and the right permissions).  I'm not sure, though, if CMKs are supported.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i ended up abandoning this approach as it gave me too many problems. I ended up providing the secrets as files in a layer that my function uses, and depending on the stage of Code Pipeline it uses the dev or production file secret.

I know they could potentially be accessed by downloading the layer zip, but for now it's just me accessing AWS and potentially my boss, so it doesn't worry me that much.

Comment: Glad to help.  You might consider the [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_lambda.html) _"to retrieve and cache AWS Secrets Manager secrets in Lambda functions without using an SDK"_.

Comment: hey @fedonev i considered AWS Parameters, but I didn't go through with that option since I read in the Docs that they don't work with cross account access. The way my setup is doesn't make that a suitable option, since my Security account centralizes secrets/params and then my Dev and Prod accounts access them on the Security account